# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package when using two modules side-by-side in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Google Cloud Function using the Python runtime. My project looks like this:

```
|-root  
   |-otherDir  
      |-main.py  
      |-requirements.txt  
      |-tasks.py
```

tasks.py is a module containing a bunch of functions. main.py looks like this:

```py
from .tasks import test

def main(request):
    #my code
```

When I attempt to deploy the contents of otherDir to Google Cloud Functions I get error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

on line

`from .tasks import test`

I've done some googling around and found that if I change it to this (i.e. not use relative imports) then it deploys successfully:

```py
from tasks import test

def main(request):
    #my code
```

However in doing so my IDE loses the ability to resolve the task module so I lose the goodness of intellisense.

How can I structure my code so that it can be deployed to Google Cloud Functions but still have my IDE able to resolve the reference to the tasks module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had word that this has been fixed: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/pull/169

Comment: Adding one critical detail for those using Gen 1 Cloud Functions. This fix is in functions_framework version 3.1.0, however version 3.0.0 is currently installed by default. 

To ensure you're using a version with the fix in place, you should add functions_framework >= 3.1.0 to your requirements.txt file.

Per the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#specifying_dependencies_with_pip), adding functions_framework to your requirements.txt is a recommended practice, so there should be no issues using the newest compatible version